# Como paso datos de un php a otro

Tags: php, ajax, variables, notificaciones, id

tengo una pagina de ingresar usuario, agrege tambien un boton de notificaciones con ajax cuyos datos se alojan en la tabla "datos". El problema es que en la pagina de cada usuario aparecen las mismas notificaciones para todos. Quiero agregar una columna mas en la tabla "datos" que almacene el mismo valor que el id de usuario para que solo carguen aquellas notificaciones que correspondan al usuario.
Mi problema es que la pagina de ingresar esta en "index.php" y el de notificaciones en "noti.php", y no se como hacer lo que les comento.

Comment: Quieres algo como variables de SESSION ?? en ellas puedes guardar un valor, y se mantendrá hasta que la sesión sea destruida, las puedes utilizar donde sean llamadas.

Comment: Hola. Creo que tu problema es el **uso que haces de php**. Puedes hacer un archivo php o muchos como comunes.php en donde se prepara todo lo que sea común a los que responden a las solicitudes y se incluyen dónde sea necesario mediante las sentencias **include**, **include_once**, **require**  y **requiere_once** dependiendo de la necesidad. consulta **[estructuras de control PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.control-structures.php)**

Comment: y una idea breve de como lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Si el usuario se ha logeado guarda en sesion su id:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["userId"] = $userId;
```

Despues donde lo necesites, puedes acceder a `$_SESSION["userId"]`